# Salesforce Email Deliverability - Bounced EMails

Tags: email, custom-object

We have Deliverability and Bounce Management setup in our org. We send the emails to our customers from a Custom Object, using Workflow rules and Email alert.
But we are not getting any notifications / Bounced email, when the email address on the Custom Object record is not proper. 
Anyone experience the same issue? If yes, what was the resolution.